# How to recover the value from a DropDownList in SelectedIndexChanged CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following code:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
DropDownList1.Items.Add("[Select city]");

while (CRegistro2.Read())
{  
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(CRegistro2[2].ToString() + " " + CRegistro2[0].ToString());
}

CRegistro2.Dispose();
CRegistro2.Close();
```

How can i add the value, not just the text or label, to recover it on SelectedIndexChanged

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of overloads to adding a list item programatically - and you're looking for this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To Add a value to each item added in the dropdownlist, use ListItem.
Check this link,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h.aspx

Example:

```
 DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1 Text", "Item1 value"));
```